# Is my code in a state of deadlock?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

On compiling my code below it seems to be in a state of deadlock, and i don't know how i can fix it.  I am attempting to write a pipeline as a sequence of threads linked together as a buffer, and each thread can read the preceding node in the pipeline, and consequentially write to the next one. The overall goal is to spilt a randomly generated arraylist of data over 10 threads and sort it.

```
    class Buffer{
    // x is the current node
    private int x;
    private boolean item;
    private Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    private Condition full = lock.newCondition();
    private Condition empty = lock.newCondition();

    public Buffer(){item = false;}

    public int read(){
        lock.lock();
        try{
          while(!item)
             try{full.await();}
             catch(InterruptedException e){}
          item = false;
          empty.signal();
          return x;
     }finally{lock.unlock();}
    }

    public void write(int k){
        lock.lock();
        try{
        while(item)
           try{empty.await();}
           catch(InterruptedException e){}
        x = k; item = true;
        full.signal();
      }finally{lock.unlock();}

  }
}

class Pipeline extends Thread {

    private Buffer b;
    //private Sorted s;
    private ArrayList<Integer> pipe; // array pipeline
    private int ub; // upper bounds
    private int lb; // lower bounds

    public Pipeline(Buffer bf, ArrayList<Integer> p, int u, int l) {
        pipe = p;ub = u;lb = l;b = bf;//s = ss;
    }

    public void run() {
        while(lb < ub) {
            if(b.read() > pipe.get(lb+1)) {
                b.write(pipe.get(lb+1));
            }

            lb++;
        }

        if(lb == ub) {
            // store sorted array segment
            Collections.sort(pipe);
            new Sorted(pipe, this.lb, this.ub);
        }
    }

}

class Sorted {

    private volatile ArrayList<Integer> shared;
    private int ub;
    private int lb;

    public Sorted(ArrayList<Integer> s, int u, int l) {
        ub = u;lb = l;shared = s;
        // merge data to array from given bounds
    }
}

class Test1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int N = 1000000;
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0;i<N;i++) {
            int k = (int)(Math.random()*N);
            list.add(k);
        }

        // write to buffer
        Buffer b = new Buffer();
        b.write(list.get(0));

        //Sorted s = new Sorted();

        int maxBuffer = 10;
        int index[] = new int[maxBuffer+1];
        Thread workers[] = new Pipeline[maxBuffer];

        // Distribute data evenly over threads
        for(int i=0;i<maxBuffer;i++) 
            index[i] = (i*N) / maxBuffer;

        for(int i=0;i<maxBuffer;i++) {
            // create instacen of pipeline
            workers[i] = new Pipeline(b,list,index[i],index[i+1]);
            workers[i].start();
        }

        // join threads
        try {
            for(int i=0;i<maxBuffer;i++) {
                workers[i].join();
            }
        } catch(InterruptedException e) {}

        boolean sorted = true;

        System.out.println();
        for(int i=0;i<list.size()-1;i++) {
            if(list.get(i) > list.get(i+1)) {
                sorted = false;
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you start the run methods, all threads will block until the first thread hits full.await(). then one after the other, all threads will end up hitting full.await(). they will wait for this signal.

However the only place where full.signal occurs is after one of the read methods finishes.
As this code is never reached (because the signal is never fired) you end up with all threads waiting.

in short, only after 1 read finishes, will the writes trigger.
if you reverse the logic, you start empty, you write to the buffer (with signal, etc, etc) and then the threads try to read, I expect it will work.

generally speaking you want to write to a pipeline before reading from it. (or there's nothing to read).

I hope i'm not misreading your code but that's what I see on first scan.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Buffer` class it flipping between read and write mode. Each read must be followed by a write, that by a read and so on.

You write the buffer initially in your `main` method.

Now one of your threads reaches `if(b.read() > pipe.get(lb+1)) {` in `Pipeline#run`. If that condition evaluates to false, then nothing gets written. And since every other thread must still be the very same `if(b.read()`, you end up with all reading threads that can't progress. You will either have to write in the `else` branch or allow multiple reads.